# Why does my redirect works randomly

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm redirecting the users in my site using a php script, it was working perfectly till last monday and suddenly it works randonly, at times it redirects to the desired page on another instance it gives an error.

The redirect url

```
devaltrack.dailyusers.com/rd?track=130&go=www.bbc.co.uk
```

The error that comes at times

> The requested URL /www.bbc.co.uk was not found on this server.

when i dig deep into it i realized that if i type the `go` value with `http` it will always work, without that it works time to time,
can anybody give me a possible clue of whats going on here

Redirecting script

```
$redirect_page= '/rccp.php';
$trusted_domain = $_GET['go'];
$track_id = $_GET['track'];

    $strsql = ("CALL select_whitelisturls($track_id)");
    $result = mysql_query($strsql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row==""){
    redirect_cookie_user($redirect_page);
}

if($row["redirect"] == 1 ){

    if (false === strpos($trusted_domain, '://')) {
        $trusted_domain = 'http://' . $trusted_domain;
        //$trusted_domain = strtolower($trusted_domain);
    }

    if ($i = strpos($trusted_domain, '/', strpos($trusted_domain, '//')+2)){
        $trusted_domain = strtolower(substr($trusted_domain, 0, $i)). substr($trusted_domain, $i);
    }else{
        $trusted_domain = strtolower($trusted_domain);
    }

    $domainarray = explode("\n", $row['domainname']);
    if ($domainarray[0] == null ){
        exit(); 
    }

    foreach ($domainarray as $value) {
        if (false === strpos($value , '://')) {
            $value = "http://".$value;
            $value = strtolower($value);    
        }else
        {
            $value = strtolower($value);
        }
        $pos = strrpos($trusted_domain, $value);
        $domain_string =parse_url($trusted_domain);
        $value_string =parse_url($value);

        if(($pos !== false) &&($pos == 0) && ($value_string['host'] == $domain_string['host'])){
            if (isset($_COOKIE["id"])){
                $_GET['id'] = $_COOKIE["id"];
                $_GET['go'] = $trusted_domain;
                header('Location: '.$redirect_page.'?'.http_build_query($_GET));
                exit();
            }else{
                header('Location: '.$trusted_domain);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    exit();
}
function redirect_cookie_user($redirect_page){
    if (isset($_COOKIE["id"])){
        $_GET['id'] = $_COOKIE["id"];
        header('Location: '.$redirect_page.'?'.http_build_query($_GET));
    }
    else{
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's interpreted as local URL path, not as URL, unless you write a proper URL including protocol prefix.

Comment: If you want help with the implementation (in case it was really working before as you claim), you will have to show said code.

Comment: sorry its my local tracking url.. wait ill edit it..

Comment: anybody has an idea about what makes the error!!!

Answer (score 1):

I do think your problem is the code that prints the redirect. If you are using the header('Location: xxxx'); then the xxxx should always has the schema (http, https, etc), or else the browser would try to navigate relatively.

EDIT:
You could do something like:

```
// For testing
$go = 'www.bbc.co.uk';                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
//$go = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk';                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

$uriInfo = parse_url($go);                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

if (!isset($uriInfo['scheme'])) {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  $go = 'http://' . $go;                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}

header('Location: ' . $go)
```

Now you would check if the schema is defined, if not, you will append 'http://'

Comment: wait ill add the code.. could u chk for any defects on it

Comment: as far as i compared there isnt a flaw in my code isnt it, i think i have done this in the above,, btw can u please chk my code above.. thanks

Comment: @user3584871 I have not seen your error in the code... the only thing I see is that it will fail if the go is 'bbc.com://', as you just check if the '://' is in the string. You might want to do the check as I did the the example.

Comment: @user3584871 what if the go is set to '/bbc.com', you would redirect to 'http:///bbc.com', that could in some browser lead to the error you posted.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont use "http://" it will search for a folder "www.bbc.co.uk" on your webspace (which wont exist). You should make the forward append an "//" before the url (which lets the browser decide if he wants https or http)